# HTML CSS style how not inherit

Tags: html, css

I need to display navigation menu with logo. Here is the JS Fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/47Ls678d/

The problem right now, the image logo is inheriting the **<** **/a** **>** tag property from the css and I am not able to the remove the top, left,and bottom margin space for the logo image.

I have tried with the code

```
 <a style="margin:0px;" href="#" class="navbar-left"><img height="55" width="160" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg"></a>
```

But not working.

css: 
    body {margin:0;}

```
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#" class="navbar-left"><img height="55" width="160" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg"></a>
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Its padding not the margin

Comment: Thanks that solved the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that "a" tag that is the parent tag of the image has padding.
If you have added this css to your code , the padding will be disappeared.

```
a.navbar-left{padding:0px;margin:0px; font-size:0px;}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```css
#myTopnav {
  height: 55px;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 18px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

.topnav a:nth-child(1) {
  padding: 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#"><img height="55px" width="160" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg"></a>
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>
```